# Extract keys with highest value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max

I need to extract all keys with the highest value in a dictionary. Following is an example of a dictionary:

```
a = {0: {0: 13, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 9}, 1: {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 12}, 2: {0: 1.6, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 11}}
```

The highest value is 12 (because a[0][0]=13 has identical keys, see below), hence I need a tuple of keys which leads to this value. In this example:

```
find_highest_value(a) = (1, 3)
```

I know how to find the key with maximum value in a non-nested environment:

```
max(c, key=lambda x: c[x])
```

Further I can access the second dictionary with fixed values:

```
max(c, key=lambda x: c[x][0])
```

which returns 1 (as a[1][0] is highest). The following code does not work, and at this point I gave up, as I have no further idea.

```
max(c, key=lambda (x,y): c[x][y])
```

Additional question: How to ignore values where both keys are equal? I.e. ignore all values a[b][c] with b == c.

Edit:

Responses to questions in the comment:

- I need keys to the ONE highest value in the full dictionary.
- It is always nested like the example. One dictionary of dictionaries, where the latter always contain key-value pairs. Consider it as adjacency matrix in a graph.

Comment: Is the dict always nested to this level, or is this for arbitrary nesting?

Comment: You want the highest value in each `nested dictionary`? In this case, 9, 12, 11? Is this the output you need?

Comment: no he wants the path to the biggest value which is (1, 3) in this case.

Comment: @MohammadRazeghi Oh, yeah, I see. Thanks

Comment: Added more details to clarify my question and answer yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
max([(x,y,a[x][y]) for x in a for y in a[x] if x != y], key=lambda x: x[2])
```

gives output

```
(1, 3, 12)
```

and will ignore duplicates as desired

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Is it possible to return just the keys? Not a real problem if not, as it is easy to extract the keys, but would be a little nicer.

Comment: I'd write `max(((x, y) for x in a for y in a[x] if x != y), key=lambda (x,y):a[x][y])` since it makes it clear that you're sorting based directly on the value in the dictionary, rather than just some arbitrary third value in a tuple. Just my personal preference though. +1

Comment: Just add [:-1] to the end

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> max((key1, key2, value)
...     for key1, subvalues in a.items()
...     for key2, value in subvalues.items(),
...     key=lambda (key1, key2, value): value)
(1, 3, 12)
```

There are numerous ways of getting just the keys. We could slice the answer:

```
>>> (1, 3, 12)[:2]
(1, 3)
```

Or only producing the keys:

```
>>> max((key1, key2)
...     for key1, subvalues in a.items()
...     for key2 in subvalues,
...     key=lambda (key1, key2): a[key1][key2])
(1, 3)
```

This is less efficient as it has to perform two dictionary look-ups.

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Is it possible to return just the keys? Not a real problem if not, as it is easy to extract the keys, but would be a little nicer.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(max(((k2, max((k for k,v in d.items() if k != k2), key=d.get)) 
                for k2, d in a.items()),key=lambda x: a[x[0]][x[1]]))
```

input:

```
a = {0: {0: 13, 1: 2, 2: 5, 3: 9}, 1: {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 1, 3: 12}, 2: {0: 1.6, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 11}}
```

Output:

```
(1, 3)
```

Comment: It however does not ignore the duplicates, if I see this correctly

Comment: @waza-ari, how do duplicates fit into it? How could max ever return more than one value?

Comment: Sorry, duplicate may not be the best word for it. From the question: "How to ignore values where both keys are equal? I.e. ignore all values a[b][c] with b == c." See updated example, query should still return (1, 3), although a[0][0] = 13.

Comment: do you mean if the keys are the same or the key and value is the same?

Comment: He means if the keys are the same. Also you got the wrong answer! (2,3) -> 11

Comment: If keys are the same. All values a[b][c] with b==c should be ignored. Thanks!